# Setting LESS_TERMCAP_* variables with $(tput ...) in ~/.profile not working

Tags: terminal, colors, less, tput

This is my `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# ...unnecessary lines skipped...
# man colors
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(tput blink) # start bold
LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput setaf 2 ; tput bold) # start bold
LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(tput sgr0)  # turn off bold, blink and underline
LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput smso)  # start standout (reverse video)
LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(tput rmso)  # stop standout
LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(tput smul)  # start underline
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(tput rmul)  # stop underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb
export LESS_TERMCAP_md
export LESS_TERMCAP_me
export LESS_TERMCAP_so
export LESS_TERMCAP_se
export LESS_TERMCAP_us
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue
```

This works, I can see colors in man pages. But when I move that lines from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` (and re-login), the colors in man pages disappears.

I really want to use `tput` because it is more clear than a heap of control symbols.

Why do `tput` not working from `.profile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tput` is not working because it needs to know the current terminal emulator from `$TERM` environment variable. When `~\.profile` is reading, there's no terminal emulator in use, so `tput` can't produce any output.

It is possible to specify which terminal capability to use in `tput` by `-T` key. So this code will work:

```bsh
LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(tput -T ansi blink) # start bold
LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput -T ansi setaf 2 ; tput -T ansi bold) # start bold
LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(tput -T ansi sgr0)  # turn off bold, blink and underline
LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput -T ansi smso)  # start standout (reverse video)
LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(tput -T ansi rmso)  # stop standout
LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(tput -T ansi smul)  # start underline
LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(tput -T ansi rmul)  # stop underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb
export LESS_TERMCAP_md
export LESS_TERMCAP_me
export LESS_TERMCAP_se
export LESS_TERMCAP_so
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue
export LESS_TERMCAP_us
```